# MongoDB recursive find query not knowing depth

Tags: mongodb

Let's say I have a collection composed by elements that looks like this:

```
{
    "uuid": "some uuid",
    "children":
    [
        {
            "uuid": "uuid1",
            "children":
            [
                {
                    "uuid": "uuid2",
                    "children":
                    [
                        {
                            "uuid": "uuid3",
                            "children":
                            [
                                {
                                    "uuid": "uuid4",
                                    "children":
                                    [
                                        {
                                            "uuid": "uuid5",
                                            "children": []
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Is there a query that allows me to get a child with a specific uuid without knowing his depth?

Comment: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/graphLookup/ will bring all children to the root array, then you can $match them. It will be quite expensive query tho.

Comment: @AlexBlex thank you. I've seen this operator. As it turns out Mongo discourages nesting documents with a depth greater than 1.
So probably my problem is due to a design flaw on how I store these data in the database.

Comment: that's also true